# laravel controller and view issue

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, sum

I need a get field value total sum. But I can't and don't know where the problem is.

`controller` code:

```
 public function index()
    {   
        $user1 = Auth::user();

        $user2 = $user1->client_id;

        $withdraws = Withdraw::where('client_id', $user2)->get();
         
        $deposits = Deposit::where('client_id', $user2)->get();

        return view('home')->with(compact('deposits', 'withdraws', ));
    }
```

`view` code:

```
@foreach($deposits as $deposit)          
  <td id="count-data-td">{{ $deposit->amount }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hey Mohammad I don't see where `total_sum` is mentioned in the code?

Comment: what is the error you currently see
and what is the structure of the deposit table

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('home')->with('transfers', array('deposits'=>$deposits, 'withdraws'=>$withdraws));
```

and view code

```
@foreach($transfers['deposits']) as $deposit)
    {{ $deposit->amount }} 
@endforeach
```

but if you need the sum you can always do  this:

```
{{ $transfers['deposits']->sum('amount') }}
```

in your case :

```
{{ $deposits->sum('amount') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function index()
 {   
        $user1 = Auth::user();

        $user2 = $user1->client_id;

  $withdraws = Withdraw::where('client_id',$user2)->get();
         
  $deposits = Deposit::where('client_id', $user2)->get();

     return view('home')->with(['deposits' => $deposits, 'withdraws',$withdraws]);
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
{{ $deposits->sum('amount') }}

{{ $withdraws->sum('amount') }}
```

**NB:** You don't need to run the foreach loop to get the sum